# .click not registering changed class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a script that will change the class of another element to avoid the script from being activated under the new class, however, it is not registering with the script, the script considers the old class to still be there.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".element1").click(function(){
  $(".element1").addClass("clicked");
  $(".element1").removeClass("element1");
});});
</script>
```

Current code is above with what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: what's the HTML that goes with it?

Comment: Yes, please add the required code

Comment: I have an updated one , this surely the one you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41413773/click-not-registering-changed-class/41413810#41413810

Answer (score 2):

The element(s) that has class `element1` was binded to a click handler on load...

Even if you remove the class from it, it still is binded to the event handler.
As you can see below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".element1").click(function(){
        console.log("click");
        $(".element1").addClass("clicked");
        $(".element1").removeClass("element1");
    });
});
```

```css
.element1{
  color:blue;
}
.clicked{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element1">element 1</div>
```

I suggest you to use `off()` like this:
*Thanks to Dashtinejad for mentionning that `.unbind()` is deprecated as of jQuery 3.0... Works the same.*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".element1").click(function(){
        console.log("click");
        $(this).off("click").addClass("clicked").removeClass("element1");

    });
});
```

```css
.element1{
  color:blue;
}
.clicked{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element1">Element 1</div>
```

And use chaining...
;)

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, `.unbind()` has been deprecated. It was superseded by the `.off()` method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.

Comment: I have an updated one , this surely the one you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41413773/click-not-registering-changed-class/41413810#41413810

Comment: Okay, question, after testing everything, I was wondering how I can reverse this effect? When the class is being removed and replaced with element1, it still thinks that it is "clicked" and not element1. using the same code didnt work for some reason

Comment: To re-attach a click handler, you have to have another element which has the "re-attach" function... I have made an example on [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/VPZyVo?editors=1011) for you.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette how can this be done with "clicked" having the reattach function rather than having another element, is the other element needed?

Comment: Finally, you want to always have a click event attached to the element... But do a different action based on the class it has. In this case, you don't need to detach/re-attach the click event. What you need is to check what is the class the element has when the click occurs. Here is another [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/MJgVLj?editors=1011) example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you can achieve it by using onclick of particular element. Here the on click listener is binding to the ".element1" in the document at the time of clicking.

if you want to execute a click event only one time then you can also use `.one()`

```
$(".element1").one("click",function(){ 
    <!-- your code here -->
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".element1", function() {
    console.log("click");
    $(".element1").addClass("clicked");
    $(".element1").removeClass("element1");
  });
});
```

```css
.element1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
.clicked {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="div1" class="element1"></div>
```

Comment: If you want to execute your event only one time then u can also use .one() as in updated

Comment: Same question to you, is there a way to reverse this script and add back "element1" while removing "clicked" on click of another element such as element 2 and repeat.

Comment: you need to add  $(document).on("click", ".element2", function() {console.log("click");
    $(".clicked").addClass("element1");
    $(".clicked").removeClass("clicked");
  });

Answer (score 1):

my solution is:  **clicked in the div**

> see one(), off(), on(); in :
>
> http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_one.asp
>
> http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp
>
> http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_off.asp

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".element1").one("click", function() {
   console.log("is clicked");
  $(".element1").addClass("clicked").removeClass("element1");
});
});
```

```css
.element1{
background-color:red;
}
.clicked{
background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element1">hola</div>
```

Comment: This yields the same problem that I had, when you click on the div "clicked" it still thinks that you are clicking element1 as seen in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".element1").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("clicked").removeClass("element1");
  });
});
```

Note here [jquery method-chaining](http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/introduction/method-chaining/) is used. You dont need to select the element multiple time to add method to it